# iOS 8 select options are truncated

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, ios8, html-select

In iOS 6 and iOS 7 select options were truncated, but could be fixed with an empty optgroup in the select:

[iOS 6 Select Menu vs iOS 7 Select Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660390/ios-6-select-menu-vs-ios-7-select-menu/20667445#20667445?newreg=c7bf857ac1394d99adc3e5a8410ce5f5)

This solution no longer works for iOS 8. Has anyone been able to resolve it?

Thank you.